# How to reset the value of one select input when another select input is selected in angular

Tags: angular

```html
...
  <select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event.target.value, 'status')" #byStatus>
    <option value ="" disabled selected="selected">IBy Status</option>
    <option>Pending</option>
    <option>Paid</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event.target.value, 'user')" #byUser>
    <option value ="" disabled selected="selected">By User</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.first_name}}  - {{user.email}}</option>
  </select>
...
```

In the `.ts` file I know which select input is selected. I tried to change the value buy using `nativeElement` but

```
this.byStatus.nativeElement.ElementRef
```

is **null**.

How to set the value of select input to default if the other is selected. So if select input 1st is selected 2nd should be set to default and if 2nd is selected then 1 should be set to default

```js
onChange(selectedVal: string, by: string) {
  if (by === 'status') {
    ...
  } else if (by === 'user') {
    console.log(this.byStatus.nativeElement.ElementRef);
    this.byStatus.nativeElement.ElementRef.value = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `nativeElement` to change your element, try using Template driven forms (`ngModel`) provided by Angular (See documentation: https://angular.io/guide/forms). You can also use Reactive forms (See documentation: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Both these methods will give you better control over your code.

To use `ngModel` in your code. You will need to import the `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

In your HTML, set the `ngModel` attribute to your select tags to bind the values to the component. With this, when you select an item from the `status` dropdown, it will update `selectedStatus` to the value of the selected option.

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChange('status')" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">IBy Status</option>
  <option>Pending</option>
  <option>Paid</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChange('user')" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected">By User</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of allUsers" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.first_name}}  - {{user.email}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your component, declare the required and set them to the default value.

```
  selectedUser: any = "";
  selectedStatus: any = "";

  onChange(changedDropdown: string) {
    if (changedDropdown === 'user') {
      this.selectedStatus = "";
    } else {
      this.selectedUser = "";
    }
  }
```

Here is a working example of the same on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-select-example)